# IBOutlet not setting to a string plus a value

Tags: ios, objective-c, iboutlet

Good afternoon, I have a question. I am trying to set an IBOutlet (a label) to a value of the number of days between 2 dates and then the string " days". Here is my code:

`_daysUntil.text = ([components day], @" days");`

components has a value; It is determined via this code:

```
    NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
NSDateComponents *components = [gregorianCalendar components:NSCalendarUnitDay
                                                    fromDate:todaytransform
                                                      toDate:dateFromString
                                                     options:0];
```

Hope this is enough to get an answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to format the string (`%ld` is the placeholder for `NSInteger`):

```
_daysUntil.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld days", components.day];
```